# How to configure access_token's lifetime in client_credentials flow? Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-b2c, clientcredential

we need to change the default lifetime of ours access_tokens. The default time is 1 hour and we need to change to 15 minutes by a Security Area request.

We have an Azure AD B2C tenant, where we created App Registrations for our Daemon Apps and Web Applications.

Web Application uses authorization_code with custom policies, here we can change the token's lifetime with custom policies configurations.

But, Daemon Apps uses client_credentials with "standard request":

```
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={CLIENT_ID}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://{TENANT}.onmicrosoft.com/{CLIENT_ID}/.default'
```

We didn't try anything yet, we didn't find the correct documentation in azure portal.

So the question is: **how we can configure the access_token's lifetime in that scenario?**

PD: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one application in my **`Azure AD B2C`** tenant like below:

[image]

When I generated *access token* using client credentials flow via Postman for above application, it has token lifetime as **1 hr** like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: {CLIENT_ID}
client_secret: {CLIENT_SECRET}
scope: https://sristackb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/{CLIENT_ID}/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

To change token lifetime to **15 minutes**, you can make use of below PowerShell script by creating one TokenLifetimePolicy like this:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId <B2CtenantId>

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "DisplayName eq 'B2CApp'"

$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:15:00"}}') -DisplayName "Valid15min" -IsOrganizationDefault $true -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id

Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I generated the **access token** again now, I got it with token lifetime as **15 minutes** like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: {CLIENT_ID}
client_secret: {CLIENT_SECRET}
scope: https://sristackb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/{CLIENT_ID}/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]